# Polymer 1.0 javascript variable not hitting control statements

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

I am trying to hide and show certain **paper-materials** depending on what `termiantePlan` is. `terminatePlan` is being passed in from MVC 5 view which is working. Once `termiantePlan` hits the control statement, its not reading it correctly...the code passes the first if statment because `termiantePlan` is not null. but once it gets to the second if statement it dosnt read that `terminatePlan = "active"`. Also, If `termiantePlan == 'noPlan'`, i still get `this.showTermPlanStatus(terminatedPlan)` everytime. I have also tried `terminatePlan.indexOf('noPlan') > -1;` This doesn't work either.

```
   Polymer({
        is: "lithium-terminate-plan",
        properties: {
            terminatePlan: String

        },
        observers: [
             "termPlan(terminatePlan)"


        ],
        termPlan: function (terminatePlan) {

            if (terminatePlan != null || terminatePlan != "active") {

                if (terminatePlan == "noPlan") {

                    this.showTermPlanStatus(noPlanSelected);

                } else if (terminatePlan == "error") {

                    this.showTermPlanStatus(terminatedPlanError);
                } 
                else {
                    this.showTermPlanStatus(terminatedPlan);

                }
            } else {
                if (this.effectiveDate == null) {


                } else {
                    this.showTermPlanStatus(activePlan);
                }
            }
        },
        showTermPlanStatus: function (showTrue) {

            this.$.terminatePlanError.hidden = true;
            this.$.terminatedPlan.hidden = true;
            this.$.noPlanSelected.hidden = true;
            this.$.activePlan.hidden = true;
            this.$.terminatePlanInProcess.hidden = true;
            showTrue.hidden = false;
        }

    });
```

Comment: to enter the first `IF`, `terminatePlan` should NOT be active - how it's supposed to enter the 1st nested `IF` as `active` then? - What you have here is a conditional error that has nothing to do with Polymer

Comment: its not, its suppose to go to the else statement. the only thing that is being read is if termiantePlan is null or not. its like it dosnt read anything else.

Comment: ok lets say active plan is not there and terminatePlan = "noPlan". It will still skip over the first nested if statment and show this.showTermPlanStatus(terminatedPlan);

Comment: even if terminatePlan = "active" i will still get this.showTermPlanStatus(terminatedPlan); but I should be getting this.showTermPlanStatus(activePlan);

Comment: what does `console.log(terminatePlan);` gives before and after `if (terminatePlan == "noPlan") {` ?